# How can I remove the default shading of a simple model in 3DS max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

I've been downloading free 3d models for a project that I'm working on, but I can't figure out how to disable the default shading. I'm using **3DS MAX 2013**.

Here's an example of a table I'm working on:

[image: Table example image]

I used the material editor to add a Diffuse material to the top of the table. As you can see, there is shading around the front rim of the table, which moves with the table as I rotate it.

Is it possible to disable this shading? If so, how can I do it? I read about Self-Illumination but I didn't have any luck in applying it to the model.

Comment: Just FYI...  This is technically off-topic, but I see no reason to close it while there is currently [a proposal that would expand this site to include 3D (amongst other changes)](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/354/should-we-rename-the-site-to-graphic-art-and-design).

Comment: @Farray Ahhh, it hadn't occurred to me that this may be off-topic, as I have seen many 3D questions here in the graphic design portion of stack exchange. Thank you for the clarification and I apologize for posting off-topic.

Comment: No worries and no apology needed.  As much as anything else, the link I posted is intended to draw attention to the Meta discussion.

Answer (score 2):

In working viewport:

- left top corner
- click right mouse btn
- Smooth+highlights
- Other visual styles
- flat

For render:

- delete lights from scene or disable lights: select light - general parameters - Light type - off
- top menu - rendering options - Rendering Method - Default Light - off
- ctrl+L

Comment: Thank you for the response! This does indeed disable shading in the viewport, but I need to be able to disable it for the render process so the final render doesn't include the shading.

Answer (score 0):

click on default shading top left then choose viewport filter, it will open a setting window - click on the settings then untick shadows down the menu